# Is there a better term than "dummy" to describe a non-functional part of a program?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, synonyms, technical

I'm searching for a different or more neutral term than "dummy" to describe a non-functional or non-interactive part of a program.

I've been using this term to refer to code in interactive charts and data visualizations that has no meaningful value, but helps render visual effects that would be hard or cumbersome to create using outside code or more complex methods.

For example, if one series in my chart is just there to add a set of arrow-shaped markers, I've been calling it a "dummy series" (always in quotes).

The third definition of "dummy" on Wiktionary (https://simple.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/dummy) seems to agree with my usage ...

> A dummy is something that is not there but people act like its there for some purpose.

... but I'm not 100% comfortable using "dummy" due to its alternate meaning of "stupid" or "unintelligent."

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: I've provided an answer, but FWIW, as a programmer myself, I don't know if I would call that code inert or a dummy series. It sounds useful to me.

Dummy code, in my mind, is code that will _never_ be executed. It has _no_ purpose. This at least serves some function, even if the user doesn't see it.

Comment: @Ares- That's not dummy code, that's *dead code*.  *dummy* things usually stand in place of *real* things, often during an interim period before the *real* thing is available.  @ Mike- I think your usage is fine and you should not be concerned that the word has other meanings.  When you *execute* your program you (hopefully) aren't concerned that *execute* can also mean *put to death*.  The context makes it clear which definition is being used.

Comment: @Jim Thank you for your thoughts and insight. Your "execute" example is truly helpful in showing correct intent when in context. One thing I will note is the "dummy series" I cited are part of the final product and not a stand-in or placeholder in an interim status.

Comment: Why would you want to have non-functional code? That makes no sense to me.

Comment: @dangph You're correct; what I'm describing **does** indeed have a function, despite its non-interactivity, so that was a misstatement on my part. Thanks for noting that.

Comment: I'm not aware of a single word, but would describe it as "only needed for its side-effects" or "for a specific side effect" or something similar. "Non-obvious" is another, vaguer term. The important thing is that the code has a function, but it's not the standard or obvious function that you'd guess from looking at it. (Similarly, you may print/display something not to actually output it but to measure the font size.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answers given are so broad as to be mere suggestions ( ancillary, auxiliary, supplementary, nonessential ...) or so subject-specific as to be far better provided on a different site (eg Computer Science.SE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms [*ancillary*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ancillary), [*auxiliary*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/auxiliary), or *[supplementary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/supplementary)* should work better.

> Ancillary: providing something additional to a main part or function
>
> Auxiliary: available to provide extra help, power, etc., when it is
> needed
>
> supplementary: Completing or enhancing something

You can also simply say *[nonessential](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonessential)*:

> not completely necessary : not essential

Comment: I'm grateful for your suggestions, alwayslearning. I do like "ancillary," but I'm curious how widely understood that term might be. I would argue that "nonessential" isn't quite a good fit, since the "dummy series" are "essential" to provide the non-interactive visual effects.

Comment: @MikeZavarello, in that case, the more commonly used *supplementary* is your friend. Although I indirectly mentioned it (as a synonym of ancillary) in my answer earlier, I have now also included definition and ODO link.

Comment: "Supplementary" reads the best to me. Thank you for updating your answer with that suggestion, and for your guidance overall.

Comment: "Auxiliary functions" are a thing. An auxiliary function is a function called by some other function, and no other function, to do part of its work. It's especially common in LISP. It's quite different from a nonfunctional or nonessential part. "Ancillary" code or functions or whatever isn't a term that's used. "Supplementary" or "nonessential" might describe what you're looking for, but they aren't terms people use in programming.

Answer (score 4):

One term that is often used in programming is [stub](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/271720/what-does-stubbing-mean-in-programming/271752#271752).

That is "filler" for a portion of the program that is not yet written.

Comment: This is not what the OP wants. The code mentioned is *not* filler but somewhat *nonessential*. They are not the same.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Tom. @alwayslearning is correct: I'm not referring to a placeholder or filler, but part of a finished product that isn't "true" data or an interactive piece.

Comment: @MikeZavarello: The "filler could be made a "non-functional or non-interactive part of a program." A "stub" usually has a minor function, but it doesn't have to. That is to say,a stub could be so that "one series in my chart is just there to add a set of arrow-shaped markers,"

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of "inert."

It's definition isn't 100 percent literal:

From Dictionary.com:

[Inert](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inert)

> having no inherent power of action, motion, or resistance (opposed to active)

Comment: "Inert" is a good suggestion, Ares; thank you. It implies non-interactivity and yet something that's present and can be observed.

Answer (score 1):

I've switched to using "sample" for when the code or value was a placeholder for something else.

Comment: Hello, jenlampton. Have you a reference showing that this is widely recognised? ELU deals with (reasonably idiomatic) usage.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/441373)

Comment: @Joachim I'm new to this SE, but how does my comment not provide an answer? The question about alternatives for the use of "dummy" in program writing. I gave one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I work in Open Source Software and there's recently been a movement to move away from ableist language in code comments and the like. I came here seeking other alternatives. I don't have a single reference to show that Sample is widely used, but There are over 100 examples in the codebase for Backdrop CMS: https://github.com/backdrop/backdrop and over 300 references in Drupal https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal. That's only two projects, so I've been looking for others.

Answer (score 0):

"Dummy variable" is a common term for a variable that is in the program but not used. As in:

```
MyClass& MyClass::operator++ (int junk); //<--junk is a placeholder, or dummy variable
```

A "dummy function" is one that doesn't actually do anything, but does allow compilation. [An IBM page on this.](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ztpf/1.1.0.15?topic=bal-dummy-function-definitions)

These terms don't have any connotation of being stupid or unintelligent. They're just placeholders. "Auxiliary functions" are a completely different kind of thing.